# ASP.Net and JavaScript custom control video player

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, media, video-player

Is it possible to reference a custom control designed in asp.net from java or javascript...

This custom control simply involves a mediaplayer object from C#. I'm looking for my own way to use a video player.

Does this makes sense?
Can you help?

Comment: You should probably clarify your question, and add any code you've tried so far to make it easier for people to help you out.

Comment: I've got a custom control created in C# and I want to use it on my webpage.